# Customising domain name using PHP

Tags: php

When we create the first php page to echo "Hello World" on the browser viewport from our local machine, we create a .php extension file, run a server (I have XAMPP) and enter localhost/filename.php in the address bar and it works.

In this case the URL shows ending in ".php" as was the file extension. How do I show a URL ending in ".com" or any other domain name?

I think one has to buy a domain and register and all. Not sure in detail how the process goes but if I'm given as an assignment to create a ".com" ending URL page without all that is there a way to do that?

Comment: by default, it would go to your index.html page located in your document root. For example, say your domain name was example.com. You would have a file called index.html in your document root folder of apache/nginx, and it will internally serve example.com/index.html when you visit example.com

Comment: u need to get domain name from some hosting providers like godaddy something. then move your files into live server using ftp.

Comment: simple get the domain name and show it to your incharge

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer :** 
You can do it using "hosts" file located at `%SystemRoot%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`. Add a domain that point to your local machine at 127.0.0.1 and you should be able to open that domain in your local machine.

for example : `127.0.0.1       abc.com`

Now to serve content from your project folder you need to create a virtual host in XAMPP.

1. Fire up your text editor with administrative privileges and open up httpd-vhosts.conf found in the C:/xampp/apache/conf/extra folder
2. Create a host as specified below :

`<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin email@abc.com
    DocumentRoot "E:\xampp\htdocs\projects\abc"
    ServerName www.abc.com
</VirtualHost>`

**Do not forget to restart XAMPP after changes.**

Now www.abc.com will serve content from your project folder.

**Long Answer :** 
It's all starts with DNS system which works on your local machine. Each OS has its own DNS resolver. So when you enter a domain name into the address bar of browser, it will be handled by local DNS resolver which will look up relative IP address related to entered domain in global DNS resolver.

Hosts file is the frontier of DNS resolver. So every request first look into the hosts file and if the entry was made for the entered domain, it will point that domain form there only. It will not try to go to global DNS resolver and serves the request from that IP

So when you edit a hosts file and enter a domain along with IP it will open a localhost and created virtual host on local web server will serves the content from specified DocumentRoot.